# Doing a count on a field in a mysql table based on a condition evaluated from a join

Tags: mysql, sql, database, date

I have a table `q_data` like so:

```
cuid  timestamp_from        timestamp_to
A1    2014-12-01 22:04:00   2014-12-01 22:04:21
A1    2014-12-04 22:05:00   2014-12-04 22:05:25
A2    2014-12-06 20:04:00   2014-12-06 20:04:21
A2    2014-12-07 19:04:00   2014-12-07 19:04:21
```

and a table `patients_` like so:

```
cuid    last_visit
A1      2014-12-03
A2      2014-12-05
```

I wish to count the number of rows per cuid in q_data such that the timestamp_to is earlier than the last_visit date in patients_. So for the data shown above, I expect my query to give the following result.

```
cuid   day_count
A1     1
A2     1
```

I am trying to do this using the following query:

```
create table tmp
    select
        q.cuid as cuid,
        count(distinct(q.query_to)) as day_count
    from q_data q
    inner join patients_ p on q.cuid = p.cuid
    group by q.cuid
    having datediff(p.last_visit, date(q.query_to)) >= 0
;
```

but I get an error:

```
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'p.last_visit' in 'having clause'
```

I shall appreciate if someone could help me understand the mistake in my query. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your select query

```
select 
q.cuid as cuid, 
count(distinct(q.query_to)) as day_count 
from q_data q 
inner join patients_ p on q.cuid = p.cuid 
group by q.cuid 
having datediff(p.last_visit, date(q.query_to)) >= 0;
```

If note closely in your having clause you have used 2 columns which are not part of the select and this is invalid and will get the error as you are getting now.

One thing you can do is moving that in the `where clause` as

```
select q.cuid as cuid, count(distinct(q.query_to)) as day_count 
from q_data q 
inner join patients_ p on q.cuid = p.cuid 
where datediff(p.last_visit, date(q.query_to)) >= 0
group by q.cuid
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot:

```
SELECT 
  q.cuid, COUNT(*) as day_count 
FROM 
  patients_ as p
LEFT JOIN 
  q_data as q 
ON 
  (p.cuid = c.cuid )
WHERE 
  (DATE(q.query_to) < p.last_visit)
GROUP BY 
  q.cuid
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't specify field in having if it don't available in select

```
create table tmp
    select
        q.cuid as cuid,
        p.last_visit as last_visit,
        count(distinct(q.query_to)) as day_count
    from q_data q
    inner join patients_ p on q.cuid = p.cuid
    group by q.cuid
    having datediff(p.last_visit, date(q.query_to)) >= 0
;
```